# Counting days difference between actions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to count number of days between actions in CaseActionHistory table.

I know that I should use datediff(day, start, end) however I have trouble in defining "end". Right now it looks like:

```
,datediff(day, convert(date,max(CA.DateAdded)), end) as [Time between]
```

So for example:

I got 1 action made on 23.05.2013 and the 2nd one done at 11.06.2013 and I need to count the difference between dates.

Ideas?

Whole query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CDV.SetId
,CAD.Description
,max(CA.DateAdded) as [DateAdded]
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.EndServiceDate
,datediff(day, convert(date,min(CA.DateAdded)), convert(date,max(CA.DateAdded))) as [Czas pomiędzy]
,datediff(day, CDV.DateImported, max(CA.DateAdded)) as [Dzień obsługi]
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join CaseActionDefinition as CAD on CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = CAD.DefinitionId
where
CDV.ClientId = 1
and
CDV.SetId IN (158,159,160,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,194,218,219,220,241,255,256,257,258)
and
CA.CaseActionDefinitionId between 28 and 33

group by CDV.SetId,CAD.Description, CDV.DateImported, convert(date, CA.DateAdded), CDV.EndServiceDate
```

[image]

So I want difference between 23.05.2013 and 05.06.2013 then between 05.06.2013 and 11.06.2013 etc etc

Comment: What _trouble_ do you have exactly?

Comment: I don't really know what to put instead of "end"

Comment: But you've mentioned `done at 11.06.2013`, isn't this the end date? So if you have this date, what's the problem?

Comment: Just i wild guess but do you want to know the difference to the date on the next row? Based on some ordering of the rows?

Comment: If start date and end date both are in the same column, How do you determine which one is start data and which one is end date ???

Comment: @Olle Johansson Exactly!

Updated first post with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to get the date difference between a date and last date value added for that ID/Person/whatever, You can do something like ..

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM (/*Your Query Will go here*/) A
)
SELECT  *,   DATEDIFF(DAY, X.Date, Y.DATE) NumOfDays

FROM CTE X LEFT JOIN CTE Y
ON X.RN = Y.RN - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Little more details would be helpful!
You may need to use self join or CTE based on the format you want to get data in.
I can help if you add more detials here..

Comment: What exactly would you need.

Comment: I understand that you are actually trying to calculate difference between two successive rows. After getting this difference, what are the values you would like return along with the difference. As I can see only one table structure here, i can give you a query involving only this table. You can join with other tables as per your need.

Comment: Sounds fine to me. I would be greatful if you could do such thing.

As soon as possible I'll try to provide you with expected results (or how I'd like them to look like).